# help 300+ image on the page, eats processor too much

Tags: jquery

I'm developing gallery in my web application and i was creating script which loads and appends new images at the bottom, when users scrolls to the bottom of the page.

But when images become around 300~, appending and scrolling process eats too much process power.

Is the any solution for this issue?

I saw everything works fine in new google images search results.

Sorry for comments. :)

http://pastebin.com/QAYXpWvC

Comment: You will need to show some code. Also, what exactly happens? Does processor usage indeed go up in the system monitor?

Comment: yes it does, chrome eats up to 50% of processor

Comment: How much memory do you have?  How much memory is a tab with your app in it consuming?  What kind of cpu % does google images consume in similar situations?  Are your images thumbnailed or are you just scaling full size images?

Comment: 2gb memory, 70mb~, Duo Core E7400, google images consume 15-25% of processor instead of 50%, full size images

Comment: really?  your app is only consuming 70mb?  On disk, what is the total size of all the images you are loading in kb?

Comment: 4.45kb each image, 110x110 px

Comment: When i'm setting timeout inside loop for images to 250ms, app eats up to 15-40%
I think i should put next image, only when it previous finished loading. 
I think it's the main reason.

Comment: show some code and we can help, otherwise, not much more I can offer.

Comment: I found the main reason. It was because i didn't wait until previous image finish loading.

Now i have created custom loop and continue looping only when onload event of previous image triggers.

I think i should do as Ankit Jain said, create empty containers for each image, so that document could receive final height instantly.

App eats usually 7-9% processor, sometimes up to 20-30% maximum, simply scrolling eats 0% now.

Comment: Bah! It eats up to 40%, when there is more images.
Everything is fine at the begining, when there is around 150~ images, but then it starts to eat a lot of processor power.

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page the results or if you are doing a 'continuous scroll' you need to remove the ones that are off screen (ie scroll in both directions).

**edit**
I investigated a little about google images.  They load about 430 images which on my machine consumes 600 megs of ram for that *single* tab in Chrome.  If your machine is low on resources, you should see spikes in performance in their UI too, not just yours.

Comment: What do you mean by removing those offscreen. Display:none or completely remove?
But what if user scrolls up again?

Comment: Google Images does not remove them off the screen

Comment: Indeed, they don't, but they are using html5 canvas to draw the copy of original image as i understand.
Do canvas eat less resources?

Comment: @Beck, @Ankit They are, however, paging results.  I'm not sure how many they are showing per page. I will add some comments to the question to request clarification.

Comment: Hmmm, i guess i will have to switch back to pagination option if i will not figure out something until tomorrows evening.

Answer (score 0):

Load only those images which are visible in the first view. Subsequently use ajax to load as user scrolls down. A lot of websites does this and **loads next page via Ajax**. This is someway similar to what Facebook does (I observed in Firefox 3.6.8). It creates place holders for all images in an large album. However it **loads only those which are visible in current view. When you scroll down, it fetches thumbnails to fill remaining view**.

Comment: So basically, i should create containers for each image with the same width and height, so that scroll bar would not bumping?

Comment: And when user is scrolling to bottom, they hide them. Hmm i'll try it.

Comment: Aka Continuous scroll, as I mentioned :)